# TouchID for Login User with database Parse.com in iOS 8.0

Tags: ios, authentication, parse-platform, touch-id

Hello to all I want to do a little question ... I'm using parse.com in my app. The login procedure of my user is through the use of parse.com with the classic method username and password that the user types in two textField.

So far everything works but I wanted to implement an additional method of login using the TouchID, but it becomes hard to implement with parse.com because the touchID identifies the impression and the user is not in the database Parse.com therefore when using the TouchID my app returns (rightly) an error because it does not recognize the user among those present in the database ...

Have any of you managed to use the method of biometric TouchID for a login created through parse.com ??? or you know if there is a method that can allow me to do this?

Thank you all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TouchId is just used to authenticate a user to the device - it does not identify a user.  You can have fingerprints for different people enrolled into the phone but there is no identity stored with them - they are just valid credentials to authenticate to the device.

You can use touchId to retrieve items from the keychain, so you can store your Parse userid and password in the keychain (the user will need to type them the first time) and then use touchID to unlock these stored credentials for future authentication.

Apple have some [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html) that demonstrates using touchID to authenticate to the keychain and for local authentication

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply, I had read of the method "keychain" but I could not really understand ... where can I find information on this ?? some tutorials ??? or explanations?

Comment: so in the keychain after configuring the Touch id the credentials.... if the password got changed on the server... then what will happen to the touch id authentication? how to update the password for touch id?

Comment: You have to detect a failed login and fall back to the username/password authentication and then update the keychain items

Comment: The keychain option offers a possibility to fallback and enter the device passcode instead of the fingerprint. Make sure you are ok with this if you want to use that technique.